# Handling cleanup actions in python by using anonymous function in list

Tags: python, list, code-cleanup

In Python, need to clean up all the actions in reverse order inside finally block.

I will explain the requirment in Perl.

```
sub fun1{

    add_1();
    verify_1();

    add_2();
    verify_2();

    remove_2();
    remove_1();
}
```

In case `verify_2()` throws an exception,  `add_1()` remains uncleaned.

This is how I handle the cleanup in Perl

```
sub fun1{
@cleanUpActions = ();
try {
   add_1();
   push (@cleanUpActions, sub {remove_1()} );

   verify_1();

   add_2();
   push (@cleanUpActions, sub {remove_2()} );

   verify_2();

   remove_2();
   pop @cleanUpActions;
   remove_1();
   pop @cleanUpActions;

} catch {
   BaseException->throw("")
} finally{
  foreach my $action (reverse @cleanUps){
    &$action;
  }
}

}
```

Tried the same logic in Python.

```
def r2():
    remove_2()

def r1():
    remove_1()

clean_list = []

def fun1():
  try:
    add_1()
    clean_list.append(r1)

    verify_1()

    add_2()
    clean_list.append(r2)
    verify_2()


    remove_2();
    clean_list.pop()
    remove_1();
    clean_list.pop()
  except:
     raise Exception
  finally:
     clean_list.reverse()
     for func in clean_list:
         func()
```

This above Python code works, but its not that I need. Instead of writing separate def , i would like to add the function block as anonymous func into the list,  like I can do in Perl.
Python Lambda only accepts expression, does not support multi line body.

Is there any other efficient way to handle such cleanup actions in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous subs are called "lambdas" in Python.

```py
add_1()
clean_list.append(lambda: remove_1())
verify_1()
```

That said, you can use the name of a function without `()` as a function pointer.

```
>>> def f():
...    print("foo")
...
>>> x = f
>>> x()
foo
```

So all you need is

```py
add_1()
clean_list.append(remove_1)
verify_1()
```

Also note that you can use `def` inside of a function, allowing you to create a multi-statement cleanup function.

```py
add_1()
def r1():
   remove_1()
clean_list.append(r1)
verify_1()
```

Comment: Thanks. In case there is no function named `remove_1` and  `remove_2`. Then how can we add only the function body here. Body contains multiple lines.

Comment: Well, you probably should have a `remove` function if not `remove_1`, in which case you could use the `lambda` approach. Still, you could use a local function as shown in the uptate to my answer